# What comic book format should you use to make it easier to turn into a web comic?

Tags: formatting, comics

What comic book format should you use to make it easier to turn into a web comic? I am thinking 3x3  or 1x3 are the best format and most flexible; otherwise, turning them into webcomics might be extremely difficult? Am I correct into assuming this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any comic book format can easily be turned into a webcomic, because in the worst case you can simply post whole pages. This is common for comic formats that don't (solely) use rectangular panels, such as a manga.

If you have something more like the traditional newspaper comic, then you can post the comic online per strip, and print it with 3 or 4 strips per page. This is more common for webcomics that update daily or multiple times a week.

It's the other way around that is hard. If you have a webcomic that relies on the "infinite canvas", there is no good way to get it on a printed page.

Comment: The "infinite canvas" problem is rife in in Korean webtoons - When they are transferred to physical media, significant rearrangement of panels are almost always necessary, and complete redraws of parts are not uncommon. Even then, the tempo control of blank spaces between panels or the dynamism of vertically extended panels are practically impossible to accurately translate.